# Regex for containing only alphanumeric characters and underscores, start with an alphabetic character

Tags: regex

I'm trying to validate Firebase event name:

> Event names can be up to 40 characters long, may only contain alphanumeric characters and underscores ("_"), and must start with an alphabetic character.

Invalid:

- `4foo` (start with a number)
- `foo bar` (contains a space)
- `foo$@bar` (contains special character)

Valid:

- `foo`
- `foo_bar`
- `Foo_Bar`

I have tried `\d?[^A-Za-z0-9_]+` which matches if there are any special characters and whitespace, but it won't match string with a digit character at the beginning.

Comment: How about `^[a-zA-Z]\w+$` ?

Comment: So something along the lines of `^[A-Za-z]\w{0,39}$` should do?

Comment: `^[a-zA-Z]\w+$`  and `^[A-Za-z]\w{0,39}$` both worked, please write them as answer, thank you

Comment: I'll leave that to @Jvdv. The extra maximum length check makes it the preferred answer.

Comment: @JvdV You could post that if you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```js
^[A-Za-z][A-Za-z0-9_]{0,39}$
```

See [regex proof](https://regex101.com/r/V0PHeq/1).

**Synonyms**:

```js
^[A-Za-z]\w{0,39}$
^\p{L}\w{0,39}$
^[[:alpha:]]\w{0,39}$
```

**EXPLANATION**

```js
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ^                        the beginning of the string
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [A-Za-z]                 any character of: 'A' to 'Z', 'a' to 'z'
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  [A-Za-z0-9_]{0,39}       any character of: 'A' to 'Z', 'a' to 'z',
                           '0' to '9', '_' (between 0 and 39 times
                           (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  $                        before an optional \n, and the end of the
                           string
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:-

regex --> `/^(?=[a-z].{39}$)(?=\w+$).+$/i`

Comment: “names can be **up to 40** characters long”, your regex accepts only 40 char long.